# Does anyone have a manual or spec regarding an NEC JAPAN 45006705-210 0356MP010

Tags: microcontroller, specifications

As the headline states.

It seems to be hard to get! The µC is in use in an Ferroli Arena A30 boiler.
A datasheet could help to know how the pin configuration. A manual should even be more awesome.
Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: This could be a custom part, or a standard NEC part marked with the electronics manufacturer's part number.

Comment: Probably an MCU with mask ROM (or laser cut ROM or OTP ROM). The part number will be unique to the firmware loaded on it - i.e., customer specific. There will be many the same with different numbers and different firmware. You won't identify the underlying part from the number.

Answer (score 1):

Matching 64pin masked parts gave 1 of several possible matches
[image]